# Reference Request - Who originally transformed $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ into $X^2+DY^2=N$?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, soft-question, conic-sections, math-history

I'm looking for the classical results which gives a transformation of the quadratic
$$ax^2 +b xy + cy^2 +dx +ey +f =0$$
into an equation of the form
$$ X^2+DY^2 = N$$
I believe it was Lagrange who originally did it, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't imagine this can be traced to one source.
On the other hand, there has been some attention to diagonalizing forms, in some quadratic forms book I have. On that note, you may just make $H$  the Hessian matrix of homogenized
$ax^2 + bxy  + c y^2 +dxz +eyz +fz^2$  and then, by repeated completing the square, construct nonsingular $P$   such that $P^T HP = D$  is diagonal.

Meanwhile:

When $a \neq 0$   and $ \delta = 4ac - b^2$ and

$g=ax^2 + bxy  + c y^2 +dx +ey +f$

If $a=0$  but $c \neq 0$   switch  $(x,y)$  so the new $a$ is nonzero.

Here we also use $\delta \neq 0$  For the revised constant term

$ w=(16fc - 4e^2)a^2 + (-4fb^2 + 4edb - 4d^2c)a$

we reach
$$ 4a \delta g =  ( \delta  y + 2ae - bd)^2  + \delta(  2ax + by + d )^2  + w $$

With $g=0$  the right hand side   is also $0.$
This way, if everything begins as integers, the final expression is all integers.

Comment: Thanks. I read a paper of Lagrange in French a while ago but I no longer have access to his Oeuvres. But this was the formula.

Answer (score 2):

Credit could arguably go to [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Stirling_(mathematician)) in his *Lineae  tertii  ordinis Newtonianae* (1717). Quoting from [Carl Boyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Benjamin_Boyer)'s reputable History of Analytic Geometry (1956):

> *One of the important additions in Stirling's work is the formal analytic treatment of general second-degree equations. Ever since
> the time of Descartes geometers had given indications of how to transform the equations of conics to normal forms, and Wallis had asserted
> that from the coefficients of the equations alone one could determine
> the characteristics of the curves. De Witt, Craig, L'Hospital, and
> Wolff had shown how to determine the shape and position of a conic
> from its equation;* ***but Stirling was perhaps the first one to complete
> in analytic detail the program of reducing the general quadratic to
> canonical forms.*** *[...] This was not really new, for similar work along these lines
> had been given frequently in the seventeenth century; but Stirling
> went further and calculated analytically from these forms the characteristic properties of the conics with respect to axes, vertices, asymptotes, and parameter -aspects which previous writers had derived geometrically or had taken over from Apollonius.*

For reference, this is the original of the relevant (starting) [page](https://archive.org/details/lineaetertiiord00newtgoog/page/n146/mode/2up):

[image]