# Math books beautifully designed

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm looking for a math books that you consider that are beautifully designed, it may be by the fonts and the colors used, the structure of the content, equations with a beautiful font, plots beautifully made with nice colors, etc.

Let's say I'm not expecting the traditional LaTeX design. They may be written in LaTeX, no problem with that, but the style has to be different.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Beautifully designed" varies from person to person. I've voted to close this as opinion-based.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, yeah, it's opinion-based, I was expecting to choose the answer with most votes.

Comment: There's an interestingly-illustrated version of Euclid's *Elements* by Oliver Byrne from 1847. It has been converted to interactive electronic form [here](https://c82.net/euclid/) by Nicholas Rougeux.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835748/25554)

Comment: No LaTeX [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483373/291201) for sure ;-)

Comment: I find books awesome that were written in the pre-LaTeX era with mechanical type writers. No kidding. [Here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/63980/optimumconsumpti00mert.pdf) an example. There are of course many more. Also: in general I like the typesetting in  books that were printed in east Germany until about 30 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Surely Francis's [*A Topological Picturebook*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68120-7) has to be in the running, right? It has (what I feel is) good design in its typesetting and styling. But obviously its main selling point is the sequence of spectaucular illustrations:

[image: a screenshot from Francis's book]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know any math book that’s as aesthetically pleasing as [*An Illustrated Theory of Numbers*](http://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.com/) by Martin Weissman. This includes the typesetting, layout and diagrams. You can see some examples of diagrams from the book on that page. One indication how excellent the diagrams are is that the page sells “art prints, adapted from images in the book” :-).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I love [Visual Differential Geometry and Forms](https://www.amazon.es/Visual-Differential-Geometry-Forms-Mathematical/dp/0691203695) of Tristan Needham. Its writing and its pictures are wonderful.

On the other hand, I suppose you know The Road to Reality, of Roger Penrose. I think it's a bit overrated, but I admit that the design is really good.